# passing intent extra to android broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have created a AlarmReceiver class which is used as broadcast receiver for alarm. The issue is that I need to send some values from the class which is setting the alarm to the broadcast receiver class.

setAlarmManager.java

```
     Intent i = new Intent(mContext, AlarmReceiver.class);
     i.putExtra(KEY_ROWID, (long)taskId); 
     PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,taskId_int,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 
     mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

I need to get the KEY_ROWID from intent in alarmreceiver class. How can I do that? The AlarmReceiver class is shown below.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
          public static final String ALARM_ALERT_ACTION ="com.android.alarmclock.ALARM_ALERT";
          public static final String ALARM_INTENT_EXTRA = "intent.extra.alarm";

     @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

             //Here I need the values from intent using bundle or anything...

    }
}
```

Comment: how do you put the time value @John?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
          public static final String ALARM_ALERT_ACTION ="com.android.alarmclock.ALARM_ALERT";
          public static final String ALARM_INTENT_EXTRA = "intent.extra.alarm";

     @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

             String keyid = intent.getStringExtra("KEY_ROWID");
    }
}
```